# Greenify kills apps, including system apps

Tags: greenify

How to fix my Samsung Galaxy Note 3 when Greenify close all apps, even system apps in my phone? My Samsung Galaxy Note 3 cannot open anymore. How can I fix my phone?

Answer (score 2):

Power your Device into Safe mode, Uninstall the Greenify App, Exit Safe Mode and Check if your phone is working.

> ### Power the Device Up in Safe Mode - Samsung Galaxy Note® 3
>
> [Website](http://www.verizonwireless.com/support/knowledge-base-88613/)
>
> *[Device-Specific Instructions]*
>
> *Safe Mode puts your phone in a diagnostic state (returned to default settings) so you can determine if a third-party app is causing your
>   device to freeze/reset/run slow.*
>
> 1. With the device powered off, press and hold the Power button
>      (located on the right edge) until the Samsung Galaxy Note 3 logo
>      appears then release.
> 2. With the logo on the screen, press and hold the Volume down button
>      until Safe mode appears in the lower left of the screen then
>      release.
>
> **Note:** The Phone goes through entire boot up process before showing Safe mode. This may take up to 45 seconds.

---

**Sidenote:** If you actually froze an app like titanium backup does, you'll have to reset your phone as you probably have frozen all the
 apps.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in linking the [original source](http://www.verizonwireless.com/support/knowledge-base-88613/). See [How to reference material written by others](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)

Comment: @Firelord I was in a rush and forgot to link the original material, will link now. Thanks for the heads up.